# Is it possible to create a false charger that drains a device's power?

Tags: physical, smartphone

Inspired by the idea of the [USB Killer](https://hackaday.com/2015/10/10/the-usb-killer-version-2-0/), I was wondering if it'd be possible to create a device that, when plugged into a mobile phone/laptop/whatever charging port, drains the charge of said device rather than charging it.

I'm inclined to assume it's not possible because a) I imagine there'd be something on the internet if it was and b) in an episode of *Mr. Robot*, a hacker gets a target to leave their phone unattended on charge by sending "100 large MMS files" to drain the battery, whereas I assume if a drain attack was feasible he would've done that. I don't know much about electronics though.

Comment: If the laptop can charge the USB Killer, then I think that's your answer.

Comment: What is the major issue with a drained battery? I'll just take my phone and plug it into a different charger.... It leaks no information, the most it does is temporarily stop me using it in a way that is common. Oh, and just for your information, I carry around a small portable battery bank I can use as a temporary power solution if I need to use the phone somewhere, so about 2 minutes downtime depending on the phone boot time.

Comment: If the phone is using an USB-C connector, there is a chance you could discharge a device while charging other, cause it is reversible by its conception - https://www.cnet.com/news/what-is-usb-type-c-phones/ - On Android it even shows you if you want to use your phone as power supply but, this attack should explore other things, since you need access to the phone to put it on that state of work, and it should take some time to dischange entirely.

Comment: And, there is this old abstract(2008) about exausing one's phone battery by using bluetooth Service Discovery Protocol. Don't know how smartphones would be affected by this attack - http://www.cs.utah.edu/~nandha/Abstract_2008.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly is easily possible. Modern smart phones have an USB otg mode, in which they play host to things like USB drives, mice, SDR dongles. In order to do so, they power these devices. So yes, you can design a charger that first charges the phone, and after a while, presumably after the user leaves the device unattended because he's certain it's getting charged, reverse their role.

However, I'm not seeing purpose in that. Discharging a phone is not a security breach. Getting physical access to one is. And as soon as a user leaves their phone unattended, you've got that. Twice that if he also was unhindered by standard security etiquette not to plug in his phone to unknown USB ports.

Comment: I'll let other miscreants come up with a penetrative usage for it - I'm personally thinking now that SWIM could leave a dummy charger or two out at a party and within an hour or two everyone would be talking to each other like normal human beings, _like back in the old days_

Comment: your hang for the nostalgic in all honors, but how is that even remotely related to information security?